# Подключение dll к проекту Qt5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Мне необходимо использовать функционал Windows Event Log. Для доступа к функция данного API нужно добавить dll к проекту. Я добавил в .pro файл следующее:

```
LIBS += -lws2_32 \
        c:/windows/System32/wevtapi.dll \
        c:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll \
```

После чего на всякий случай добавил `wevtapi.h` и `#pragma comment(lib, "Wevtapi.lib")`везде где необходимо.

Но MinGW в упор не видит функций и типов:

```
EvtOpenChannelEnum
EvtNextChannelPath
PEVT_VARIANT
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> 'EvtOpenChannelEnum' was not declared in this scope hChannels = EvtOpenChannelEnum(NULL, 0);

Что я делаю не так?

код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winevt.h>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winevt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wevtapi.lib")


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    EVT_HANDLE hChannels = NULL;
    hChannels = EvtOpenChannelEnum(NULL, 0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

LIBS += -lws2_32 \
        c:/windows/System32/wevtapi.dll \
        c:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll \
        c:/Windows/System32/shlwapi.dll

LIBS += -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -lwevtapi -lshlwapi



CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = untitled7
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: `LIBS += -lkernel32 -lwevtapi`

Comment: Не помогло, всё так не видит

Comment: Попробуйте `#include <WinEvt.h>`.

Comment: Как я уже писал выше пробовал - не помогло

Comment: 1) Вы нигде не писали, что пробовали `WinEvt.h`. 2) В таком случае нужен минимальный компилируемый пример.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51514/discussion-between---and-kff).

Comment: Добавил код, в человекочитаемом виде

Comment: сами dll не нужно добавлять в pro файл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимые Вам функции и типы объявлены в заголовочном файле `winevt.h`. Однако, они "обёрнуты" в `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)`. Значение `0x0600` означает, что они доступны только на *Windows Vista* и выше. Поэтому необходимо ***перед*** всеми включаемыми файлами определить константу `_WIN32_WINNT`. Тогда код примет следующий вид:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winevt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    EVT_HANDLE hChannels = NULL;
    hChannels = EvtOpenChannelEnum(NULL, 0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Впрочем, можно не "засорять" исходные тексты такими определениями и добавить в `.pro`-файл следующую строку:

```
DEFINES += _WIN32_WINNT=0x0600
```

Далее, требуемые функции реализованы в динамической библиотеке (DLL) `wevtapi`, поэтому нужно явно указать компоновщику на необходимость её использования, добавив в тот же `.pro`-файл следующее:

```
LIBS += -lwevtapi
```

Теперь компоновщик при сборке `.exe`-файла проекта будет использовать также файл `libwevtapi.a`, в котором сказано, что функции находятся в библиотеке `wevtapi.dll`. Тем самым компоновщик добавит информацию о необходимости подключения этой библиотеки к исполняемому файлу.